# Reading attributes of Empty XML Elements using XSLT

Tags: xml, xslt

I could parse the normal XML using simple style sheet and display the content. But, I encountered below scenario, where I need to read a specific attribute tagged under the `expression` attribute from the empty elements of the XML and display the value.

`<expressionTerm>` is an empty element and I wanted the value of the attribute `expression` from it. `expression` contains the calculation methods which are used on our internal tool.

XML:

```
<rule internalID="FD1" name="L1_test" identifier="test1">
  <ruleConditions>
    <condition internalID="0" identifier="arg0">
      <operator id="or" />
      <children>
        <condition internalID="0" identifier="arg0">
          <operator id="IS_TRUE" common="true" />
          <children>
            <expressionTerm internalId="0.1" identifer="arg0" expression="count(Number of Customers)" expectedReturnType="Boolean" />
          </children>
        </condition>
      </children>
    </condition>
  </ruleConditions>
</rule>
```

XSLT

```
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="1.0">
  <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes" />
  <xsl:template match="/">
    <html>
      <body>
        <h1 align="center">Basic Details</h1>
        <table border="3" align="center">
          <tr>
            <th>Name</th>
          </tr>
          <xsl:for-each select="rule/rulecondition/condition/children/condition/children">
            <td>
              <xsl:value-of select="expressionTerm/@expression" />
            </td>
          </xsl:for-each>
        </table>
      </body>
    </html>
  </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

i used normal XSL patterns to read the `expression` values, but I only get empty page when transformed.

Could you advise how to read the `expression` attribute? Please let me know if I am missing something important.

Comment: Your sample doesn't parse as well-formed XML as you can't have an attribute value delimited by double quotes containing unescaped double quotes, like you have in `expression="count("Number of Customers")"`. As for selecting an attribute, that is basic XPath `//expressionTerm/@expression`, it doesn't depend on whether the element has any child nodes or not. But you need well-formed XML to start with.

Comment: Please show us what you tried. It's a very simple problem and we need to see where you went wrong. To access attributes, it doesn't matter in the slightest whether the element is empty or not.

Comment: Thank you @MichaelKay.. Below is my XSL.. i kept my style sheet simple to check if the solution is achieved. But it displays the html and xml does not get parsed.

Comment: <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
xmlsns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform&quot">
<xsl:output method="xhtml" indent="yes"/>
<xsl:template match="/">
<html>
<body>
<h1 align="center"> Basic Details</h1>
<table border="3" align="center">
<tr>
<th>Name</th>
</tr>
<xsl:for-each select="rule/rulecondition/condition/children/condition/children">
<td><xsl:value-of select="expressionTerm/@expression" /></td>
</xsl:for-each>
</table>
</body>
</html>
</xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>

Comment: Thank you @MartinHonnen.. Quotes enclosing "Number of Customer-s" was a typo. corrected now. Regret for inconvenience. But, other than the quotes enclosing Number of customers, do we have any other factors , that tend to prevent well formed xml..

Comment: Neither your XML nor your XSLT code are syntactically valid. Please post code *you are actually using* not something you hastily copy-pasted without testing it at all. I've updated your question and fixed the syntax errors. Make your own edits if your code is actually different. Include any error messages you get.

Comment: Also you are not paying attention to detail. Your XPath goes `rule/rulecondition` but the name of the element is `<ruleConditions>` with an capital `C` and an `s` in the end. Focus.